# Machine readable Community Mobility Reports during COVID-19 control measures

Tags: data-request, covid19

Google is providing PDF reports for regions to understand how mobility and crowding has changed during the Coronavirus pandemic.

https://www.google.com/covid19/mobility/

Each country/region has a PDF with sub-regions. For example, Switzerland: (PDF) https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/2020-03-29_CH_Mobility_Report_en.pdf

**Where can I find this data that is easily machine readable?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Community Wiki

---

#### 1. Scrapes the regional categories from ALL the PDF files

(my own repo) https://github.com/philshem/scrape_covid19_mobility_reports

([more details](https://twitter.com/philshem/status/1246511863795527680?s=20))

direct links to data (two formats, same info):

- CSV: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/philshem/scrape_covid19_mobility_reports/master/data/mobility_reports.csv
- JSON: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/philshem/scrape_covid19_mobility_reports/master/data/mobility_reports.json
- [Tableau Public dashboard](https://public.tableau.com/profile/philip.shemella#!/vizhome/XNPMHW8ERD2MV2EP6AB37HG82SWZH2SN6GHHZ4HNRY/Dashboard1) (filter on country)

[image]

---

#### 2a. Digitization of line graphs

https://github.com/nacnudus/google-location-coronavirus

> Convert the PDF files to SVG format, and extract the trend lines.
>
> Extract text from the PDF.
>
> Pair up the text with the trends.

[image]

---

#### 2b. Digitization of line graphs for US/Canada

Code: https://github.com/kylemcdonald/covid-mobility-data

Data: https://github.com/kylemcdonald/covid-mobility-data/releases/tag/2020-03-29

Details: https://twitter.com/kcimc/status/1246505356471107585

[image]

---

#### 3. Scraping the aggregate changes for the entire country/region

https://github.com/patrikpolyak/google_covid19_community_mobility_reports_data

very cool fetching script for all PDFs: https://github.com/patrikpolyak/google_covid19_community_mobility_reports_data/blob/master/fetch_pdfs.sh